# Converting Short circuit solar cell (5v to 50mA)

Tags: solar-cell

How to convert solar cell short circuit current to Voltage. Because i need to display it to a 10bit micro controller. The voltage must within 0-5V.  I'm using a 3V 50mA (max output) solar cell.

Solar cell produce current when short circuit and produce voltage when open circuit.

i have tried so many methods but fail.

I tried transimpedance amplifier. but fail since it can only work for current that is in microAmp. i get negative value. for example 20mA gives me -2V. but if i go more than 25mA the value turns positive. Im tried using LTC1050, Tl081, LM741. i use 100ohm as rf. Inverting input. the non inverting is grounded and he solar cell + is to te -ve input and + to ground.

I tried using transistor but fail again. i used BC108, BC557, BC547, BC327, BC337, 2n5551.

I tried using hall sensor ACS712 which can sense up to 5A with sensitivity of 190mA. but fail because the Vo for 0 current is equal to Vs/2, which is 2.5V. the max value that i get didn't even reach 2.6 V. Which is too small.

I spend the last 2 months trying to think of a solution. So much time spend, energy and wacking my brains off but always meet a dead end with every method i tried.

Please, Please help me. I'm running out of time here. I have less than a day to figure this thing out or else i'm doom. Your help is really appreciated.

**EDIT**

Hi, sorry about the stupid comment. I'm new to proteus and circuit design. So as a newbie, i tend to ask weird question.

Anyway, i tried simulate your circuit from 0-55mA(my solar cell max current)  and it works.

[image: Trans Op Amp]

But im wondering,

1) Will it works on Solar cell?
2) Will the result still the same using single supply?
   (a few voltage drop would be fine since its a simulation)
3) can i use voltage divider to reduce the V? cause i tried and the output is "nan".
4)I look up the data sheet of the ic and its a dual op amp. How do i connect it?

5) can you teach me how to do the calculation?
6) can you please provide a circuit with (0-55mA) range that does not exceed 5V because my Microcontroller can only take 5v. eg. 55mA-4.93 V. 
And Thank you so much for your effort to help me. Really Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transimpedance amplifier does invert the voltage, but if you bias the circuit you could get it to output positive values. I don't know what your current (mA) range is, but this can be calculated so that for all input values in mA can be converted to a positive voltage on the output.

Example circuit:

[image]

In this circuit you bias the positive input with a voltage. To ensure that the input current dynamic range maps to the output voltage dynamic range you have to select correct feedback resistor and voltage to the positive input.

EDIT:

Here is a simulation of a circuit using LTSpice that I did. Here a sine wave with 40 mA peak-to-peak is mapped to about 0 to 4.8 V:

[image]

Comment: my range is 0 to 55mA. ok, i will try

Comment: based on the simulation i made i did get positive value but the increment is very small.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I updated my answer. Please remember to upvote/accept answer when/if this helped you =)

Comment: i simulate your circuit and for 1mA the output produce is nan. and after i increase the current to 20mA, it produces -ve value. i think this is because of im using a DC source supply since my solar cell produce dc current. why are you using AC supply current?

Comment: And can you please increase the range up to 55mA. that is the max output of my solar cell.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Your maximum current multiplied with the feedback resistor is the maximum voltage out. \$V = R*I\$.